# Booting option using two different OS

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I installed Ubuntu on my partition drive, the system is running on Windows 10, when  I switch on my PC it doesn't  give me option to choose Which OS to load from what do I do

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps:

1. Remove all your external drives.
2. Boot into Windows, and on the login page, click on the Power symbol and click on Restart while holding the Shift key.
3. In the Advanced Options menu that appears, choose 'Boot from device'.
4. If you find an option for Ubuntu there, click on it. It'll restart and you'll find the Grub menu when it restarts.
5. Log in to Ubuntu, open a terminal and type the following command:

   sudo grub-install /dev/sda
6. Reboot, and the grub menu should show up.

In case you are unable to follow steps 3 or 4, only hacks will be able to get you the grub menu.